# Постепенная отрисовка элементов в adapterView

Tags: android, gridview, lazyloading

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Суть в следующем: создаю приложение для итернет магазина, продукты там распределены по подкатегориям (как и везде),которые в свою очередь распределены по общим категориям. Содержимое подкатегории я загружаю в gridView, т.е. для каждого продукта отрисовывается ячейка, которая содержит изображение продукта, цену, выпадающий список с весом(порцией), названием, ценой, изображением-гамбургером для popup меню, названием продукта, кнопкой "добавить в корзину" и ещё несколькими элементами. Все они безусловно нужны. При загрузке объемных подкатегорий появляется проблема, а именно - адаптер съедает всю оперативную память. И если он не съедает ее на первоначальной загрузке, то в процессе скролла съест точно:)

содержимое ячейки gridView создаётся программно (без xml шаблона), данные для продукта я получаю с сервера в JSON. Т.е. я делаю AsyncTask на запрос JSONa, который содержит все продукты категории, в onPostExecute на его основе создаю объекты Product, на основе массива Product создаю ячейки gridView, куда подгружаю картинки при помощи UniversalImageLoader. В адаптер передаю уже готовый ArrayList с View, которые возвращаю в getView по индексу.

Если создавать новый View для ячейки GridView в AsyncTask'е, то компилятор ругается, говорит, что вью необходимо создавать в основном потоке. если на рубеже - в onPostExecute, когда загружены данные и уже готовится содержимое GridView, то приходится очень долго ждать прежде, чем увидим содержимоое категории, и в итоге на больших категориях все равно рискуем получить коллапс памяти.

Чтобы не было коллапсов памяти возникла идея сделать постепенную отрисовку gridView, на манер того, что можно увидеть на PlayMarket, сначала загружается часть списка, после её загрузки - следующая, и так, пока не будут отображены все продукты. Каким образом можно научить адаптер работать таким образом? Буду очень признателен за ссылку на реализацию такой идеи или на библиотеку, которая может с этим помочь.

**Обновление**

Адаптер

```
private final class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ItemProductInGridView> views = new ArrayList<>();

    public GridAdapter(ArrayList<ItemProductInGridView> views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemProductInGridView getItem(int position) {
        return views.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public android.view.View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return views.get(position);


    }
}
```

таск

```
private final class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            String category = null;
            try {
                category = Connection.getHttpString(Data.url_domain + Data.url_category + Data.CatalogData.gridview_parent); //getHttpString возвращает конвертированный в строку поток, полученный по юрлу
                JSONObject categoryJSON = new JSONObject(category);
                JSONArray productArray = categoryJSON.getJSONArray("product");
                int productCount = productArray.length();

                for (int position = 0; position < productCount; position++) {
                    allProductsInCurrentCategory.add(new Product(Data.CatalogData.gridview_parent, productArray.getJSONObject(position), null)); // парсим JSON и делаем объекты Product
                }
            } catch (JSONException | ParseException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return category;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) throws RuntimeException {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            bar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
            textView.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
            gridView.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

            productsInGridView = setProductsList(allProductsInCurrentCategory); // сортировка продуктов (по доступности на текущую дату)
            for (Product p : productsInGridView) {

                viewsForCurrentCategory.add(new ItemProductInGridView(
                        getActivity(),
                        p
                )); // viewsForCurrentCategory это ArrayList с View, который в дальнейшем передаётся адаптеру, ItemProductInGridView - ячейка в GridView
            }
            gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(viewsForCurrentCategory);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        }

    }
```

В общем то ничего необычного. Но если, как вы сказали, использовать convertView, или setTag-getTag - паттерн холдер, как я понимаю, то продукты начинают повторяться. Основная загрузка памяти приходится на onPostExecute, где сначала парсится json, потом сортируется, потом создаются вьюшки

Answer (score 2):

Вы удивитесь, но в ListView (GridView) можно отображать хоть 100 миллионов записей и без тормозов и нехватки памяти вовсе. ListView содержит 10 (сколько влезает на экран плюс 1,2) view, при прокрутке в них меняются только данные.

Посмотрите ролик [The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) с Google IO **2010**. В особенности обратите внимание на раздел Gotchas and don'ts - о том, что кэшировать view ни к чему, о том, что создание своих view плюс scrollview применимо для нескольких элементов, потому что listview слишком мощный инструмент. Т.е. вы изобретаете велосипед.

ЗЫ Вполне возможно, что стоит уже переходить на RecyclerView (в особенности если списки у вас редактируемые). Хотя там пока возможностей может каких-то не хватать...

Answer (score 1):

GridView, как и ListView практикует повторное использование View. Поэтому вам ненужно пересоздавать View для каждой ячейки. В адаптер вам приходит convertView одним из параметров. Если он != null, значит нужно просто заполнить его правильными данными, а не создавать новый. К тому же, нет абсолютно никаких преймуществ в том, чтобы создавать View программно вместо того, чтобы использовать xml разметку.
Также вам необходимо использовать паттерн ViewHolder. Он ускорит работу. Еще хорошо бы организовать постраничную загрузку данных.

Comment: Если я подключаю convertView, то почему то некоторые продукты в списке начинают повторяться. Точнее длина списка остаётся прежней, но состоит он всего из продуктов 6-10, которые повторяются порой по нескольку раз. А вопрос мой как раз и был о постраничной загрузке данных, я несколько туманно выражаюсь :) Каким образом её можно реализовать? Есть совет или ссылка на хороший мануал?

Comment: @АлександрТарабрин без повторного использования View (convertView) постраничная загрузка не поможет. Выложите код.

Comment: разобрался с холдером, подскажите пожалуйста хороший мануал по постраничной отрисовке элеменов